# Как посчитать количество пользователей, которое выводится по запросу, используя только sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Доброго дня!

Есть задача посчитать количество пользователей, которым больше определенного количества лет.
Таким запросом я вывожу всех пользователей, кому больше 20 лет:

```
SELECT *,  (YEAR(current_date())-YEAR(date_of_birth)) as age FROM `user` HAVING age > '20'
```

Вопрос: как посчитать количество пользователей, которое выводится по данному запросу не используя ничего, кроме sql?

p.s.
Пробовал разные варианты с count(), но так ничего и не вышло...

Comment: @makbeth, в одном запросе - никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM user WHERE (YEAR(current_date())-YEAR(date_of_birth)) > '20'`

Это подсчет количества. Вы [тут](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Counting_rows.html) смотрели? Вроде неплохие примеры.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM user WHERE date_of_birth < NOW() - INTERVAL 20 YEAR;
```

Вот так будет выглядеть ваш запрос =)

Comment: Ваш ответ тоже, безусловно, верен, но т.к. @A1essandro ответил быстрее и ближе к условию... Отдельное спасибо за INTERVAL. Буду юзать. =)

Comment: @makbeth, ответ тов. @ua6xh будет правильнее, т.к. если по `date_of_birth` построен индекс, то только здесь он будет задействован.

Правда, я бы еще `NOW() - INTERVAL 20 YEAR` убрал и заменил значением, рассчитанным заранее. Тогда этот запрос имел бы все шансы на попадание в кэш.